# Connecting to SQL Server 2017 from VS2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

The version of SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 [ 14.0.3294.2 (X64) ].

The VS2008 has SP1[Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986) installed, but I get an error while trying to connect:

> This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 are supported

If the data provider is changed to Data Provider for SQL Server to .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB, the connection would be established but the error "The selected object(s) use an unsupported database provider" pops

Comment: *Why* are you trying to use Visual Studio 2008 with SQL Server 2017? SQL Server 2017 came out 9 years after that version of VS; of course it's not going to be supported by it. Time to update your version of Visual Studio.

Comment: You might be out of luck. What are you trying to do? Can you use [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) instead?